# vb.net For Each loop on specific textboxes

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, foreach

I have an ComponentOne Input panel 'inputPanel' pulling records from a database,

I want to validate all the boxes except for the Name textbox 'txtNAME',

the 'check' is a function to test for no special characters

```
For Each ctrl As Control In inputPanel.Controls

            If ctrl.Name <> "txtNAME" Then
                check= ctrl.Text
                If NumText(check) = False Then
                    MessageBox.Show("You can only Enter Numbers and Text for this field", "Invalid Input", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                    ctrl.Focus()
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End If
        Next
```

It is still checking the txtName for special charatcers

any help?

Comment: Is the name exactly correct?  Your comparison is type-sensitive.

Comment: the name is correct, its ignoring the <>

Comment: For what its worth, comparing the name, like that, isn't great.  I'd recommend `If ctrl IsNot txtNAME Then` instead.

Comment: Do you have, In this panel, other kind of controls? (a label for example)

Comment: yea labels and textboxes, it just ignores the isNot too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limit your loop only to textboxes, discarding controls like labels or buttons present in the same controls collection

```
For Each txtBox In inputPanel.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)
    If txtBox.Name <> "txtNAME" Then
        check= txtBox.Text
        If NumText(check) = False Then
            .....
        End If
    End If
Next
```

You could also discard the unwanted textbox with

```
For Each txtBox In inputPanel.Controls _
        .OfType(Of TextBox) _
        .Where(Function(x) x.Name <> "txtNAME")
   check= txtBox.Text
   If NumText(check) = False Then
        .....
   End If
Next
```

Without discarding the non TextBox controls you loop passes also every label inside the panel control collection to the NumText method and, probably, it is the label text that triggers the error message, not the txtNAME box-

Comment: Neither of them work, Very strange must be the c1 panel. ill just have to use ifs for them. Thanks any way